# Creating Java DataInputStream data in Python

Tags: java, python

I have a Java program that uses a `DataInputStream` for storing object data.

Example:

```
  DataInputStream tInput = new DataInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream(aDirectory + "/ResultItemInfo.dat"));

  this._text = tInput.readUTF();

  this._image = tInput.readUTF();

  this._audio = tInput.readUTF();

  this._random = false;
  if (tInput.read() == 1) {
    this._random = true;
  }

  this._hasMenu = false;
  if (tInput.read() == 1) {
    this._hasMenu = true;
  }
```

Nice, isn't it?

There is an existing dataset, and now I have to add some records. If the tool that I am required to make was written in Java too, this would be pretty easy. Unfortunately, it is written in Python, so I have to discover a way how to create files that can be read from the Java application using Python.

Is there any easy way to do this?

As a last resort, I could:

- Modify the Java app and use XML. This would break compatibility with all existing data, so I really don't want to do it.
- Use Jython. Possible solution, but I want pure C-Python.
- Reverse-Engineer the data format. Not a good solution either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a string to be readUTF-able, it must contain two bytes of counter and then exactly as many bytes of UTF-8 encoded data as counter says.

So I suggest this piece of code should write a unicode string `data` the way what `readUTF()` could read:

```
encoded = data.encode('UTF-8')
count = len(encoded)
msb, lsb = divmod(count, 256) # split to two bytes
outfile.write(chr(msb))
outfile.write(chr(lsb))
outfile.write(encoded)
```

The `outfile` must be open in binary mode (e.g. "`wb`").
This is according to description of Java interface `DataInput`. I did not try to run this, though.